# How to set paint order in CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a CustomScrollView with 3 childs.
I want to render 3rd child over 2nd child.

I'm using sliver because i want to render a box below the list view and when user scrolls the box will scroll up. this behavior is working but the problem is list view renders below the box.

here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF26B89A),
            expandedHeight: 350,
            pinned: true,
          ),
          AppBarOverflow(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              color: Color(0xFF26B89A),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed([
              buildItem(),
              buildItem(),
              buildItem(),
              buildItem(),
              buildItem(),
              buildItem(),
              buildItem(),
              buildItem(),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  Widget buildItem() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 3.0),
        child: Card(
          child: Container(
            width: 400,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}


class AppBarOverflow extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {

  AppBarOverflow({Widget child, Key key}): super(child: child, key: key);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement createRenderObject
    return _AppBarOverflowRenderObject();
  }

}

class _AppBarOverflowRenderObject extends RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter {

  _AppBarOverflowRenderObject({
    RenderBox child,
  }) : super(child: child);

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null && geometry.visible) {
      context.paintChild(child, offset);
    }

  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    if (child == null) {
      geometry = SliverGeometry.zero;
      return;
    }
    child.layout(constraints.asBoxConstraints(), parentUsesSize: true);
    var _scrolled = -(constraints.viewportMainAxisExtent - constraints.remainingPaintExtent * 2);
    if (_scrolled < 0)
      _scrolled = 0;
    geometry = SliverGeometry(
      paintExtent: child.size.height,
      maxPaintExtent: child.size.height,
      paintOrigin: -(_scrolled / 3),
      layoutExtent: 10,
    );
    setChildParentData(child, constraints, geometry);

  }

}
```

result is 
[image]

result i want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subclass `RenderViewport`, override `childrenInPaintOrder` and `childrenInHitTestOrder`, you can control paint order in a general way.

Something like this:

```
  @override
  Iterable<RenderSliver> get childrenInPaintOrder sync* {
    if (firstChild == null) {
      return;
    }

    if (hollowSliver != null) {
      yield hollowSliver;
    }

    RenderSliver child = firstChild;
    while (child != center) {
      if (child != hollowSliver) {
        yield child;
      }
      child = childAfter(child);
    }

    child = lastChild;
    while (true) {
      if (child != hollowSliver) {
        yield child;
      }
      if (child == center) {
        return;
      }
      child = childBefore(child);
    }
  }
```

So how to get the special hollowSliver? override `performLayout`:

```
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    super.performLayout();

    // TODO: We don't need collection all children every layout, but it works.
    final children = [];

    var child = firstChild;
    while (child != null) {
      children.add(child);
      child = childAfter(child);
    }

    assert((() {
      return children
              .map((s) {
                var sliver = s;
                while (sliver is RenderProxySliver) {
                  sliver = sliver.child;
                }
                return sliver;
              })
              .where((s) => s is RenderSliverHollow)
              .length <=
          1;
    })(), "Only one SliverHollow used in one ScrollView");
    hollowSliver = children.firstWhere((s) {
      var sliver = s;
      while (sliver is RenderProxySliver) {
        sliver = sliver.child;
      }
      if (sliver is RenderSliverHollow) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }, orElse: () => null);
  }
```

The `RenderSliverHollow` is our custom sliver which will paint first, hit test last.

Usage:

```
EnhancedScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverHollow(),
    OtherSlivers...
  ]
)
```

You don't need scrollController or NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I've made it another way. Do you need something like this?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController scrollcontroller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollcontroller = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        print(scrollcontroller.offset);
      });
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollcontroller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: scrollcontroller,
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF26B89A),
              expandedHeight: 350,
              pinned: true,
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            _FirstItem(scrollcontroller),
            _Item(),
            _Item(),
            _Item(),
            _Item(),
            _Item(),
            _Item(),
            _Item(),
            _Item(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _FirstItem extends StatelessWidget {
  _FirstItem(this.scrollcontroller);
  final ScrollController scrollcontroller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: scrollcontroller,
          builder: (_, __) {
            var height = 230 - scrollcontroller.offset;
            var maxHeight = 90.0;
            return Container(
              color: Color(0xFF26B89A),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: height < maxHeight ? height > 0 ? height : 0 : maxHeight,
            );
          },
        ),
        _Item(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _Item extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 3.0),
        child: Card(
          child: Container(
            width: 400,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my problem with a similar solution but generally I wanted to know if it's possible to do these sort of things with Slivers

Answer (score 2):

We can not be able to order but you can use animation to archive in any case if you're still wanting to have your way then here is the partial implementation.

```
const CARD_HEIGHT = 100.0;
const CARD_ELEVATION = 5.0;

class CardCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  var clipHorizontalMargins = HORIZONTAL_PADDING - CARD_ELEVATION;
  var cardEdgeCurve = 5.0;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    var maxTopStart = CARD_HEIGHT / 2.4;
    // Draw a straight line from current point to the bottom left corner.
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(clipHorizontalMargins, size.height);

    path.lineTo(clipHorizontalMargins, maxTopStart);

    path.lineTo(size.width - clipHorizontalMargins, maxTopStart);
    path.lineTo(size.width - clipHorizontalMargins, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

and update your AppBarOverflow with clip

```
 AppBarOverflow(
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: CardCustomClipper(),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              color: Color(0xFF26B89A),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Partial is because you still need to cut or draw the path for the quadratic brazier curve from the top left and top right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you fo the answer. But It only works only on one widget